# Named pipe between C++ and Python: unable to read from C++

Tags: python, c++, linux, macos, pipe

My objective is to run a python and C++ process in lockstep using named pipes for communication. That is:

1. C++ process sends some message (delimited by `\n`) on PIPE_1
2. Python process reads message (also delimited by `\n`), sends response on PIPE_2
3. C++ reads message
4. Repeat 1..3

The messages contain arrays (possibly multi-dimensional), so I intend to use a library like `protobuf` to serialize the message to write to the pipe.
However, my C++ process blocks on `std::getline` and is unable to read from PIPE_2 until the python process is killed manually (at this point the C++ process gets the message). I suspected this might be a buffering issue, so I tried to call `flush()` as well as write `\n` to the pipe, but neither seems to work.
I am open to other solutions that are fast enough (I will be passing messages back and forth frequently), but would like to know where I'm going wrong here. My code is running on an Intel based Mac if that helps (the eventual deployment environment will be a linux one).

I rewrote a minimal version of the C++ code in python and this produces the correct behaviour (messages sent and received by both processes in lockstep, no blocking).

Below are minimally reproducible code samples:
Python process -

```py
import errno
import os

pipe1 = '/tmp/pipe1'
pipe2 = '/tmp/pipe2'
try:
    os.mkfifo(pipe1, mode=0o777)

except OSError as oe:
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

try:
    os.mkfifo(pipe2, mode=0o777)
except OSError as oe:
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise


# blocks here until writer opens read_pipe
read_pipe = open(pipe1, 'r')
write_pipe = open(pipe2, 'w')
print('opened pipes')

while True:
    r = read_pipe.readline().strip('\n')
    print(f'received {r}')
    if not r:
        print("Sender terminated")
        break
    write_pipe.write(f"Response: {r}\n")
    write_pipe.flush()
    print("wrote response")
```

C++ process:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    std::string pipe1 = "/tmp/pipe1";
    std::string pipe2 = "/tmp/pipe2";

    int writes = 10;
    std::ofstream write_pipe(pipe1, std::ios::out);
    std::ifstream read_pipe(pipe2, std::ios::in);
    
    std::cout << "Opened pipes" << std::endl;
    while (writes--) {
        write_pipe << "Some useful message" << std::endl;
        printf("sent message\n");

        printf("Reading response...\n");
        std::string response;
        std::getline(read_pipe, response);
        printf("Received response: %s\n", response.c_str());
    }
    write_pipe.close();
    read_pipe.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Python version of the C++ code that produces the correct behaviour. I use `time` to time a round trip of messages (time from message sent to reading response), and it's around 10^-4 seconds.

```py
pipe1 = '/tmp/pipe1'
pipe2 = '/tmp/pipe2'

write_file = open(pipe1, "w")
read_file = open(pipe2, 'r')

writes = 10
while writes > 0:
    writes -= 1
    start_time = time.time()
    write_file.write("Test message" + "\n")
    write_file.flush()
    print("sent message")

    response = read_file.readline()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"response was {response}")
```

Comment: Works for me. When I try to run the two first code snippets, both processes terminate successfully.

Comment: @Homer512 can I check what OS you're running? It doesn't work for me on MacOS (on an Intel MBP) for some reason.

Comment: I ran it on Linux, the python process seems to terminate after receiving 1 response for some reason, and the C++ process reads empty messages after that until termination. My intention was for them to send 10 messages to each other. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Jayanth, You wrote that your minimal reproducer "produces the correct behaviour". If your real program blocks then it is almost certainly because you are trying to send messages larger than can be buffered by a pipe. Each Unix like OS has different (sometimes configurable) limits on the amount of data that an OS pipe can buffer. Originally the buffer was just 512 bytes. These days it is common for the buffer to be 8 KB to 256 KB. Can you modify your minimal reproducer to cause the problem?

Comment: I'm also running this on linux. Did you accidentally start the C++ program first, which would create normal files if the pipes do not exist yet? Try removing them, then be careful to start the python program first

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your solution. The primary problem is that both programs are opening */tmp/pipe1* for writing and */tmp/pipe2* for reading. Which means that you don't actually have a bi-directional communication channel. It also means the opens deadlock because a blocking open for writing will not return until a process opens the fifo for reading.

A more subtle problem is that `std::getline()` won't return until the fifo is closed because it isn't seekable. So even if all the other problems are fixed the use of `std::getline()` won't allow the C++ program to process each line and tell the Python program it has done so.

Finally, your two programs do not act as a producer/consumer pair that operate in lockstep. Notice that they both start by writing a message intended for the other program. Rather than one of the programs waiting for a message from its peer.

Comment: "both programs are opening /tmp/pipe1 for writing and /tmp/pipe2 for reading" False. "std::getline() won't return until the fifo is closed because it isn't seekable" False. "they both start by writing a message" False.

Comment: I was wondering for some time how you could get this answer so very wrong. Then I figured it out: You assume the first and last code snippets form the two programs, don't you? But it's the first two that are supposed to work together. The last one is just a re-implementation of the C++ in Python. That's why nothing you wrote actually applies to the question